# zte mf286 port forwarding for Hikvision DVR

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, ipv6, dvr

I have setup port forwarding on ZTE MF286C as described here:

https://portforward.com/zte/mf286/

[image: port forwarding]

There is a Hikvision DVR on 192.168.0.10

I have checked public address of the router using
https://whatismyipaddress.com/

When I connect from the internet server to the public IP address using browser and HTTP, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? (besides not having static IPv4)
Can I use ipv6 somehow to get static address?